# how to add search button in textbox (windows 8)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

how to add button in textbox (windows 8)?

something like this in xaml? This is a special control?

[image]

Comment: Simple positioning and use of a border.

Comment: Very simple in XAML. Its literally just a matter of taking a textbox and adding an image. Try looking [at this StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135436/inlcude-a-button-in-a-textbox)